# Right to left dialog/pallete/windows in Extendscript for Adobe InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript, adobe-scriptui

I need a right to left Window (is a object in ScriptUI). In C#, a form has tow properties RightToLeft and RightToLeft layout that create a right to left form.

How can I do this in Extendscript?

Answer (score 0):

In ScriptUI, the alignment property can be set on either the container itself or on its children. Given that w is your window :

```js
var w = new Window('dialog');
w.preferredSize.width = 200;
var t1 = w.add('statictext',undefined, "I am right justified");
t1.alignment = "right";
var t2 = w.add('statictext',undefined, "I am centered justified");
t2.alignment = "center";
var t3 = w.add('statictext',undefined, "I am left justified");
t3.alignment = "left";
w.show();
```

Comment: Could you create a multi-column listbox that its first column be in right side?
Or could you create a panel that its title be in the right side?

I worked with the alignment property but I couldn't. Finally I decide to implement my forms in C# and call them from Extendscript. In Visual Studio I have control over all things and the IDE and intellisense are much more better and easier.